# How can I override the default forums and container pages with a view?

Tags: views, nodes

I need to override the default pages that come with forums with views. I need to still include the default info as per the screenshots. I can't seem to get the right relationships and the correct aggregation for the counts. Any insight would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So the problem is the "Replies" column in the second table? Isn't there something in Views which does that?

Comment: For some things you could make your own Views field handlers..

Comment: Try to create view with same path, it will override the default display.

Comment: @ARUN It's not just overriding the path, it's about getting the correct relationships and aggregation.

Comment: Are you using Advanced Forums? It might be difficult to get everything in one view. You should consider using https://drupal.org/project/views_field_view but yes performance might be a problem ;)

Comment: Yeah, I was considering this. I though there may be a way to do it without using that module. That kind of query may be quite a performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Advanced Forum](https://drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) module, which provides many advanced features, and overrides the default forum listing with views and panels. It is not a replacement module for core forum but an enhancement.

If you don't want to use it, you can at least take a look at how they've overriden the core forum listing and make your own implementation.

Comment: I already looked at this. Advanced forum provides some extra forum listings, but it doesn't override the core pages. There are a few clues there that help me but not enough to do what I need to do.

Comment: You're right. I've just checked it now. It overrides the forum topic listing, but not the forum listing.

Comment: Although your answer is not really correct, I have assigned the Bounty to you as the deadline is approaching and I don't want it to go to waste. I do appreciate the effort though. Hopefully someone else can help me out with an answer eventually. :(

Comment: Thank you for the bounty, although I couldn't help. I'll look into that on the weekend and play around with views, if you don't get any reasonable answers.